# Spring security 403 response on POST\PUT\DELETE

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I'm trying to get some Role-based authorization working on spring, but I have trouble with 403 responses on POST\PUT\DELETE requests. I've been looking for solutions elsewhere but provided solutions with disabling csrf do not solve the issue.
This is my HTTP config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_TRAINER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PATCH, "/user/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_TRAINER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_TRAINER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_TRAINER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE,"/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_TRAINER", "ROLE_ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll();   

}
```

When I debug my code, only GET requests make my program go through the UserDetails objects to  provide the Roles collection (as defined below)

```
 public class BrevisFitUser extends User implements UserDetails {

public BrevisFitUser(final User user) {
    super(user);
}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
   return getRoles()
           .stream()
           .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getName().toUpperCase()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

On a PUT request for instance, this is the log I get:

```
2019-11-20 13:28:47.560 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [PUT /exercise/strap/3 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Basic c2ltb24ua25lejpzaW1vbi5rbmV6
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 7a829877-6de4-4746-8e27-63677f0160d2
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Length: 75
Cookie: JSESSIONID=45F53EE556C13E672E6ECFD5865B5FD6
Connection: keep-alive

{
    "unitLength": 29,
    "name": "Yellow strap home marked smaller"
}]
2019-11-20 13:28:47.560 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.t.util.http.Rfc6265CookieProcessor   : Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=45F53EE556C13E672E6ECFD5865B5FD6
2019-11-20 13:28:47.561 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter     :  Requested cookie session id is 45F53EE556C13E672E6ECFD5865B5FD6
2019-11-20 13:28:47.561 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request PUT /exercise/strap/3
2019-11-20 13:28:47.561 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2019-11-20 13:28:47.562 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    :  Not subject to any constraint
2019-11-20 13:28:47.563 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /exercise/strap/3 at position 1 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2019-11-20 13:28:47.563 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /exercise/strap/3 at position 2 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2019-11-20 13:28:47.563 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@e2265dfb: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@e2265dfb: Principal: com.brevisfit.api.model.user.User[ iduser=1 ]; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffde5d4: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: 45F53EE556C13E672E6ECFD5865B5FD6; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_TRAINER'
2019-11-20 13:28:47.563 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /exercise/strap/3 at position 3 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2019-11-20 13:28:47.563 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /exercise/strap/3 at position 4 of 15 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2019-11-20 13:28:47.564 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set encoding to UTF-8
2019-11-20 13:28:47.564 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/exercise/strap/3
2019-11-20 13:28:47.564 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@25ff6f87
2019-11-20 13:28:47.565 DEBUG 15456 --- [nio-8080-exec-5] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Based on the issue with the csrf, I have added the following code to the configuration:

```
private Filter csrfHeaderFilter() {
    return new OncePerRequestFilter() {

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                        HttpServletResponse response,
                                        FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

            CsrfToken csrf = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class.getName());
            if (csrf != null) {
                Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "XSRF-TOKEN");
                String token = csrf.getToken();
                if (cookie == null || token != null
                        && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {

                    // Token is being added to the XSRF-TOKEN cookie.
                    cookie = new Cookie("XSRF-TOKEN", token);
                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    response.addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    };
}

private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
```

And have tried with removal of antMatchers and just require authenticationi:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().httpBasic()
            .and()
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
            .and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), SessionManagementFilter.class); // Register csrf filter.
}
```

Any idea, why such behaviour?

Comment: Is the role you try your requests maybe on `ROLE_CLIENT`? Because the only difference between your GET and PUT is the `/` in the ant match and a different role

Comment: I changed the code so there are no differences in the roles expected and the url patterns. Issue persists. Still don't understand, why only on GET requests my code calls the getRoles() method but not in other requests

Comment: Can you look at "response message" apart from "response code"? If you are using browser, may be webconsole --> network tab?

Comment: I'm using postman and there I just get the Forbidden message.

Comment: And it's also strange that users with inssuficient roles have GET request access. For instance, I tried with a user with Client role only and I still get a valid response on the GET request.

Comment: Implementing `Custom Authentication Provider` would helpful here. https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider